# Editor.js Rendering in Next.js

Tags: editor

I am trying to implement `Editor.js` in my `next.js` project but first it was showing the error

[image]

[image]

Then I searched and get next/dynamic method and loaded the import as dynamic method:

[image]

And then I get this error:

[image]

Now I have remove the useEffect and initializing the editor and No error is coming , the page is loading normal but the editor is not initialized in the holder "editorjs":

[image]

[image]

I am trying to implement editor.js ( Blocked type editor ) to post the blogs in my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you. I added the `loading` param in the `dynamic` function and it works.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Editor  = dynamic(
    () => import('@editorjs/editorjs'), 
    {ssr: false, loading: <p>loading...</p>}
);
```

or you can refer here https://github.com/codex-team/editor.js/issues/1790